# Why spring @autowired is null?

Tags: spring

I'm trying to autowire a service in my rest controller like these:

rest controller:

```
@ApplicationPath("/greetings")
@Component(immediate = true, service = Application.class)
public class RestControllerApplication extends Application {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;    

    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return Collections.<Object>singleton(this);
    }


    @POST
    @Path("/getUploadType")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public JsonObject getUploadType() {
        ...
        myService.findUploadTypes();
        ...

    }

}
```

service:

```
@Component
public class UploadService {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UploadService.class);

    @Autowired
    private OneDAO oneDAO;

    @Autowired
    private TwoDAO twoDAO;

...
}
```

but in my rest controller, uploade service is null. Why?

Comment: Issue with component scan which cannot detect the UploadService?

Comment: It seems like you're mixing jax-rs annotations with Spring ones. Maybe a java ee container is providing you the rest controller instead of Spring

Comment: @Pelocho yes, this is the problem...how can autowire a spring bean into jax-rs component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got access to my bean, with these few line of code:

```
WebApplicationContext context = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
MyService myService = context.getBean(MyService.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses its own set of annotations. Instead of `@Path` plus `@[HTTP method]` you should use `@RequestMapping`.

You can find an example [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

There is also an extended example [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/)

Comment: the problem is I'm using liferay 7 that want rest services built with jax-rs, but all my application is made with spring and I need to inject spring bean into this jax-rs rest controller

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a `UploadService` as `@Component` but trying to *autowire* a `MyService` instance in your controller...

There are two options: you can declare correct service type in your controller or you can make `UploadService` inheriting from `MyService`.